# Google Plus sign in using OAuth 2.0 scrolling issue

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, google-oauth, google-plus-signin

I am looking for some beginner help for implementing the Google Sign In library using Swift in Xcode 7.2 (I didn't use CocoaPods). I followed the steps listed here: https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/sdk/ to manually install the SDK. I've added all the stated linked frameworks specified here and the libz.1.1.3.tbd file. From here I didn't type any code into my **AppDelegate.swift** file.

I have managed to successfully log in using OAuth 2.0 - Google sends me an email to confirm a new device has signed in. The problem comes when I reach the 'APP_NAME would like to:' app permissions page where the user should find the option to click the Allow button. Here it doesn't allow me to scroll down to find the button in the simulator.

I have only modified the below two files:

**GSignIn-Bridging-Header.h**:

```
#import <GoogleSignIn/GoogleSignIn.h>
```

**ViewController.swift**

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, GIDSignInDelegate, GIDSignInUIDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var signInButton: GIDSignInButton!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().delegate = self
        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().uiDelegate = self

        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().clientID = "(my.correct.clientID)"

        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().scopes.append("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login")
        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().scopes.append("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me")

        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().signInSilently()
    }

    func signIn(signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInForUser user: GIDGoogleUser!, withError error: NSError!) {
        if let err = error {
            print(error)
        }
        else {
            performSegueWithIdentifier("idSegueContent", sender: self)
        }
    }


    func signIn(signIn: GIDSignIn!, didDisconnectWithUser user: GIDGoogleUser!, withError error: NSError!) {

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

}
```

The *relevant* error displayed on loading the simulator is:

> 2016-01-11 18:19:44.045 GSignIn[10378:448732] Can't find keyplane that supports type 5 for keyboard iPhone-Portrait-PhonePad; using 3561727473_Portrait_iPhone-Complex-Pad_Default

Comment: I've reworded the question now to prevent confusion with previous duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

This turned out to be an easy fix. I rotated the screen to landscape and back again to portrait to display the 'Allow' button, however don't know what caused this issue in the first place.